# Sending SOAP request using Python Requests

Tags: python, soap, python-requests

Is it possible to use Python's [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to send a SOAP request?

Comment: How's this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15569330/2620328

Comment: not supposed to use suds ;

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi why not? It's the only tool suitable for the job.

Comment: You can pass a `requests.Session` to [zeep](https://pypi.org/project/zeep/).

Comment: @IanStapletonCordasco even in 2013 suds was dead.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

It is indeed possible.

Here is an example calling the Weather SOAP Service using plain requests lib:

```
import requests
url="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL"
#headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
body = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
              <ns1:Body><ns0:GetWeatherInformation/></ns1:Body>
         </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"""

response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)
print response.content
```

**Some notes:**

- The headers are important. Most SOAP requests will not work without the correct headers. `application/soap+xml` is probably the more *correct* header to use (but the weatherservice prefers `text/xml`
- This will return the response as a string of xml - you would then need to parse that xml.
- For simplicity I have included the request as plain text. But best practise would be to store this as a template, then you can load it using jinja2 (for example) - and also pass in variables.

**For example:**

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('myapp', 'templates'))
template = env.get_template('soaprequests/WeatherSericeRequest.xml')
body = template.render()
```

Some people have mentioned the suds library. Suds is probably the more *correct* way to be interacting with SOAP, but I often find that it panics a little when you have WDSLs that are badly formed (which, TBH, is more likely than not when you're dealing with an institution that still uses SOAP ;) ).

**You can do the above with suds like so:**

```
from suds.client import Client
url="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL"
client = Client(url)
print client ## shows the details of this service

result = client.service.GetWeatherInformation() 
print result
```

**Note:** when using suds, you will almost always end up needing to [use the doctor](https://suds.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html#fixing-broken-schema-s).

Finally, a little bonus for debugging SOAP; TCPdump is your friend. On Mac, you can run TCPdump like so:

```
sudo tcpdump -As 0
```

This can be helpful for inspecting the requests that actually go over the wire.

**The above two code snippets are also available as gists:**

- [SOAP Request with requests](https://gist.github.com/toast38coza/17e2ad6c2cfa2e96b0b1)
- [SOAP Request with suds](https://gist.github.com/toast38coza/c7342fcc1dd5762d4c02)

Comment: what if the service requests username and password? where to note them?

Comment: The suds code snippet now gives "suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error". Seems like the server is closed.

Comment: @toast38coza http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL --> Server Error in '/WeatherWS' Application. Please update the example.

Comment: @toast38coza Where do I get information for headers and body variables in the requests example above?

Comment: The Suds documentation is no longer available on fedorahosted.org. Here's [a link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310112216/https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation) to a snapshot of the documentation on the Wayback Machine.

Comment: @toast38coza can you suggest me to any alternative of response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers). you use header for this request. I want to implement same process in framework like zeep or suds. I need exact code example.

Comment: What's about SSL request?

Comment: @MehediHasan Welcome to SO! You probably will not receive an answer because your comment with an exact example is too narrow.

Comment: I want to have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...` in a xml file and read from it like `..data='"""' + xml + '"""',..`, but result is `...errorCode>502</errorCode>\n<errorDescription>XML error..`. Do I need to parse xml in python here? Your example works without file. I think xml parsing is not needed here because I have xml input, not output.

Comment: Regarding my comment 12 hours ago, during sleep I got the enlightment that I do not have to parse anything but make sure that xml is `valid` and can check it with a `parser` like `minidom` in `python`.

Comment: @OrangeDog doctor is here
https://suds.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html#fixing-broken-schema-s

Answer (score 4):

Adding up to the last answer, make sure you add to the headers the following attributes:

```
headers={"Authorization": f"bearer {token}", "SOAPAction": "http://..."}
```

The authorization is meant when you need some token to access the SOAP API,

Otherwise, the SOAPAction is the action you are going to perform with the data you are sending in,

So if you don't need Authorization, then you could pop that out of the headers,

That worked pretty fine for me,

Comment: Thank you.  But can you elaborate on this a little more?  I have gotten to a point where I am binding a client to the right service.  I am able to now call the function of the service I want (changing that function name results in an error... so I know I'm close).  But I don't know how to pass an API and that's the error I get now.