# How do I call a web service method when using python 'requests' library?

Tags: python, ssl, nginx, https, client-certificates

How do I call a web service method when using python 'requests' library? My code looks like this:

```
import requests

CERT = r'/path/to/cert.crt' #Client certificate
KEY = r'/path/to/key.key' #Client private key
CACERT = r'/path/to/ca.crt' #Server certificate chain

session = requests.Session()
session.cert = (CERT, KEY)
resp = session.get('http://www.smartcallesb.co.za:8091/SmartcallServices2/SmartloadService?wsdl',
                   verify=CACERT)

#print resp.content
session.close()
```

How would you amend the above code to call a web service function called 'getDealerBalance()'? Please illustrate.
If it is not possible is there a way to do this in python? If so please help me with an example. 
Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide more information on the web service function? Is it exposed as a URL endpoint that you are able to hit?

Comment: No. It is not exposed as a url end point. The only thing I have is the wsdl: http://www.smartcallesb.co.za:8091/SmartcallServices2/SmartloadService?wsdl

Comment: Check this answer out - seems it will be what you need! http://stackoverflow.com/a/26506633/7145986

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it

Comment: I tried to follow the example using the 'requests' library and added both a body and headers and printed resp.json() and I get the error 'ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded'. The 'suds' library example seem to be close to what I had in mind but it does not seem to apply security using mutual certificates, that is use client certificate client private key and server public certificate.

Comment: How can I change the suds example to use mutual certificates as I described? I did search for suds example but did not find one that fits exactly what I want.