# Zeep vs Requests for SOAP APIs in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, python-requests, zeep

So I know that Python's `requests` module can be used to handle REST APIs, and as per this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175489/sending-soap-request-using-python-requests), `requests` can also handle SOAP APIs as well.
I've worked only with REST APIs so far, but of the few people I know who work with SOAP APIs, they almost **always** use another module `zeep`.

Is there anything I'm missing?
Why is there a need for a whole seperate module, when it is possible using `requests` as well - and more importantly, why doesn't anybody just uses `requests` instead of using `zeep`?

Comment: `zeep` uses `requests` under the hood. `zeep` helps you to convert Python objects SOAP (XML) objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ease of use and reusability. While you could use the requests module and write raw XML,  Zeep is a high level interface which generates the XML automatically