# Python call SOAP API without wsdl

Tags: python, api, web-services, soap, ispconfig

i need to call a SOAP API. My problem is that this api **doesn`t** provide wsdl. Its the ISPConfig Remote API written in PHP.

Is there a Python Module which is able to call a Soap ws **without** wsdl?

I know my question was asked before, but there is **no** real answer provided for my issue. I hope you guys can help me this time.

Comment: The point of feeding a WSDL to a client library is to simplify the calls to the web service by having the library take care of all the "plumbing code". Without a WSDL you have to build the plumbing yourself. I assume there is some documentation as to how to structure the messages, if there is no WSDL to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bogdans comment is right, the WSDL is just the contract between Webservice provider and consumer, you might use it for code generation but it is not a must (although very helpful).

SOAP is "simply" (okay it's not, anyway ;) specialized/standardized XML via HTTP(s). Therefore you don't really need special modules for doing the call itself, you just need a HTTP library which is capable of sending HTTP-POST requests.

Have a look here for an example:
[Sending SOAP request using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175489/sending-soap-request-using-python-requests)